# Print Report only 6 data for 1 page

Tags: php, html, css

i create a report. i try print preview this report.

but i want show 6 data/page  page size a4 (landscape).

i already try loop 24 data. and try print preview in google chrome
there 1 data must be down to page 2

see my picture
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

then i check page 2 already same.

this page 2
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

How to fix this, i want report show only 6 data/page

this is my full code, you can try in localhost.

```
    <style>
    #caption
    {
        color:white;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-align:center;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
    }
    table
    {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td 
    {
        padding: 0px;
        font-family:arial;
        font-size:13px
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

    th {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
    
<table align="center" width="100%" border="1">

    <tr>
        <td colspan="7" style="vertical-align: top;" id="caption"><font size="3">Data Pendaftar</font></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    $x = 1;
    while($x <= 24) 
    {
        
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td id="caption">Foto Siswa/i</td>
        <td id="caption">Nama Lengkap Siswa/i</td>
        <td id="caption">Tempat Lahir</td>
        <td id="caption">Tanggal Lahir</td>
        <td id="caption">Usia</td>
        <td id="caption">L/P</td>
        <td id="caption">Agama</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" rowspan="3">
            <img border="1" src="https://akphoto4.ask.fm/769/854/890/910003014-1s093lj-dc47ceo09kenpt5/original/avatar.jpg"style="width:80px;height:80px;">
        </td>
        <td align="center">Vasco Da Gama</td>
        <td align="center">Spain</td>
        <td align="center">01 February 1800</td>
        <td align="center">79</td>
        <td align="center">L</td>
        <td align="center">Kristen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="caption" colspan="2">Alamat</td>
        <td id="caption" colspan="2">No. Telpon | No. Hp </td>
        <td id="caption" >Tanggal Daftar</td>
        <td id="caption">Status</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Spain</td>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">0800000000</td>
        <td >07 Februari 2000 13:15:33</td>
        <td align="center">Pending</td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    $x++;
    } 
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, you could create a separate table per page with only 6 rows. Only display the "Data Pendaftar" on the first page, add `class="break"` to every table *except the table on the last page* and add a CSS rule `table.break{page-break-after:always}`. I added a `<br />` after each table, so it looks good in the browser before it prints. This will always print 6 rows per page, even when you're accidentally in portrait mode...

```
<style>
    #caption{color:white;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;background-color:#4CAF50}
    table{border-collapse:collapse}
    th, td{padding: 0px;font-family:arial;font-size:13px}
    tr:nth-child(even){background-color:#f2f2f2}
    th{background-color:#4CAF50;color:white}
    table.break{page-break-after:always}
</style>
<?php $i = 1; while ($i <= 4) { ?>
    <table align="center" width="100%" border="1"<?php if ($i < 4) { ?> class="break" <? } ?>>
<?php if ($i == 1) { ?>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="7" style="vertical-align: top;" id="caption"><font size="3">Data Pendaftar</font></td>
    </tr>
<?php } $x = 1; while ($x <= 6) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td id="caption">Foto Siswa/i</td>
        <td id="caption">Nama Lengkap Siswa/i</td>
        <td id="caption">Tempat Lahir</td>
        <td id="caption">Tanggal Lahir</td>
        <td id="caption">Usia</td>
        <td id="caption">L/P</td>
        <td id="caption">Agama</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" rowspan="3">
            <img border="1" src="https://akphoto4.ask.fm/769/854/890/910003014-1s093lj-dc47ceo09kenpt5/original/avatar.jpg"style="width:80px;height:80px;">
        </td>
        <td align="center">Vasco Da Gama</td>
        <td align="center">Span</td>
        <td align="center">01 Feb 1800</td>
        <td align="center">79</td>
        <td align="center">L</td>
        <td align="center">Kristen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="caption" colspan="2">Alamat</td>
        <td id="caption" colspan="2">No. Telpon | No. Hp </td>
        <td id="caption" >Tanggal Daftar</td>
        <td id="caption">Status</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Spain</td>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">021000000 | 0800000000</td>
        <td >07 Februari 2000 13:15:33</td>
        <td align="center">Pending</td>
    </tr>
<?php $x++; } ?>
    </table>
    <br />
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

Comment: Glad to be of help and you resolved the initial parse error.. :-)

Comment: Thank's bro, this work. by the way this landscape only 6 data.
how to add 8 or 9 data in potrait mode ??

Comment: It depends. If you're doing this for your own company and you know exactly how many rows there are per page, you could try out how many rows fit per page. If 8 rows fit per page: 24 : 8 = 3. So you make 3 $i loops and 8 $x loops. instead of 4 & 6. But if this is for your clients: play it safe and stick to 6 rows, because you cannot predict if they're going to print landscape or portrait.